# Creating multiple relations under a single entity (Database Design)

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to design a relational database (postgres) which contains multiple tables under a single entity. In this example I have a store.

The store has many customers, staff, products. They are all related to the store through a "store_id"

[image: current schema]

I want to also link customers to a staff member. But I can't just add staff_id to the customers table, because this could allow a customer to be associated with a staff member from any store.

Is it possible to allow customers to be related only to staff which both the customer and staff are a member of?

Basically how do I prevent the below from happening?

[image: bad link]

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by applying a multi column foreign key constraint.

For customers, I keep the store_id foreign key, add a staff_id foreign key. Then also add a foreign key constraint against staff.store_id and staff.id

```
staff_id integer REFERENCES staff(id),
store_id integer REFERENCES stores(id),
CONSTRAINT customers_staff_id_store_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (staff_id, store_id) REFERENCES staff(id, store_id)
```

This enforces a rule so customers can only be associated to staff of the same store

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Person (user) USR exists.
--
user {USR}
  PK {USR}
```

```
-- Store STO exists.
--
store {STO}
   PK {STO}
```

```
-- Staff member (person) USR works at store STO.
--
staff {USR, STO}
   PK {USR}
   SK {USR, STO}

FK1 {USR} REFERENCES user  {USR}
FK2 {STO} REFERENCES store {STO}
```

```
-- Customer (person) USR shops at store STO.
--
customer {USR, STO}
      PK {USR}
      SK {USR, STO}

FK1 {USR} REFERENCES user  {USR}
FK2 {STO} REFERENCES store {STO}
```

```
-- Staff member STF manages account of customer CST
-- in store STO.
--
acc_mng {CST, STF, STO}
     PK {CST}

FK1 {CST, STO} REFERENCES customer {USR, STO}
FK2 {STF, STO} REFERENCES staff    {USR, STO}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```